# Deploy Java application with Rest web services in Openshift server

Tags: java, openshift

I´m trying to deploy java application in OpenShift server. My application is divided in four projects: BBDD, Bussiness, Web Services and Web. When I create the application with openshift, it´s created this structure: src(this one has java, resources and webapp folders), webapps and pom.xml. I don´t know how to organize my projects into that structure to upload to the server.
I have put my web structure on webapp folder inside src. Then, I put the other projects on java folder. When I executed the application I can see my web pages and I can navigate for all of them but, when I call to a webservice I have the following error:

Http/1.1 404 not found

Thanks in advance,
Iban

Comment: You should state the actual commands you used to create your openshift project (eg is it a JBOSS AS project?).

Comment: Yes!!!!! Finally I could deploy my application and I have working on the openshift server. Sorry for not answering before. I have been very busy with my works. To solve my problem I have been learning about maven because I have never work with it, it´s really helpful and not very difficult. I packed my proyect in a war with al my projects and it works. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If I helped could you press the tick box next to my answer to accept it as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Openshift is expecting to compile the application on their server using the pom.xml then run the application it built. To do that your project needs to be a [maven webapplication project](http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/). Only when you have tested it locally would you expect that committing the code to your openshift server (using `git`) would it be able to compile and run the app successfully.

This means that you should **not** be uploading files using an SCP upload tool; you should be committing your source using `git` to your openshift server for it to compile then run your app.

The way I typically work with maven and openshift is to add a fragment of xml into the pom.xml to enable the [jetty-maven-plugin](http://eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-maven-plugin.html) to be able to use `mvn jetty:run` to build and launch the project to test it locally. If-and-only-if it works locally do I try to deploy it. That command is 'zero install' as maven downloads the jetty jars and runs them over your project.

Redhat openshift tends to promote redhat jboss AS application server as a Java solution so if you go down that route you should try `mvn package`to make the war file and test it against a local jboss install before expecting it to work on the server. There is an approach where rather than committing code for the server to build and run you can build an `EAR` file locally and have that pushed to the server.

At the bottom of this answer I have a link to a demo I wrote which shows my preferred approach. I create my apps as a [DIY cartridge](http://www.openshift.org/documentation/oo_cartridge_guide.html#diy) which is an empty shell then customise the scripts in the `.openshift` folder to start the Java server of my choice. I use maven to build my webapp which I run using the jetty-maven-plugin to debug locally in Eclipse (maven IDE plugin lets me "debug as... > maven > "jetty:run"). Then I configure the pom.xml to build my whole app plus the jetty Java webserver into one huge runnable jar. Then I edit the start script to use "java -jar" to run my full app.

If you are using a DYI cartridge you don't need to use maven; I have used sbt as the build tool to create a runnable jar. You simply have to modify the scripts in the `.openshift` folder to download and run the tools you choose.

The demo I made GitHub at the link below has instructions on how to deploy it on openshift. So you may want to get that running then after you can both debug it locally and push it to your openshift server then rip out my code and add in all yours:

https://github.com/simbo1905/zkmongomaps